# Spring checkbox onLoad event not firing

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp and I create a spring checkbox like this:

```
<form:checkbox path="someList" value ="someId" onload = "javascript:alert(1);"/>
```

But the alert does not get called on page load. I am trying to call a javascript on load of the checkbox where i will execute some custom functionality.
Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a spring-mvc question as much as html. The form:checkbox will translate to an html input tag of type checkbox. The html input tag does not support the onload attribute. For a full list of attributes refer to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp. A recommended step would be to initialize everything required onload with the body tag.

Comment: Definately check on the attributes, but dont use w3schools.  See http://w3fools.com/ for interesting info.